# ktor client post multipart/form-data

Tags: kotlin, telegram, ktor

How can I post file as multipart/form-data use ktor client? I want to use it for telegram bot API "send document".
I need to achieve the same result as the curl command

```
curl -F document=@"path/to/some.file" https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=<chat_id>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading files to telegram bot api using ktor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639980/uploading-files-to-telegram-bot-api-using-ktor)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [submitFormWithBinaryData](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.request.forms/submit-form-with-binary-data.html) method to send [mutlipart/form-data request](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#upload_file). Here is a solution:

```
val client = HttpClient(Apache) {}

val file = File("path/to/some.file")
val chatId = "123"

client.submitFormWithBinaryData(
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=$chatId",
    formData = formData {
        append("document", file.readBytes(), Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${file.name}")
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: I see many examples like these but i hope nobody uses them in production because what if the file in question is 10MB... it will be leaded into memory and crash the phone.

Comment: Can you tell how to import this File in CommonMain.

Comment: Please can you look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77731866/472270 ?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is large, you won't want to read the whole thing into memory. Instead, you can stream the upload.

```
val file = File("path/to/some.file")
client.submitFormWithBinaryData(
  url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=$chatId",
  formData = formData {
    append(
      "document".quote(),
      InputProvider(file.length()) { file.inputStream().asInput() },
      Headers.build {
        append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${file.name.quote()}")
      }
    )
  }
)
```