# How can I pass the body form-data in ktor?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

```
            val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.post(endpoint) {
                headers {
                    append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, getAuthorizationHeader())
                }
                formData{
                    append("attachment", attachment)
                }
            }
```

the formData mentioned here is not correct it seems.
This api works perfectly in postman when i pass the form-data in body tab. but i don't know how to do that here in ktor. i read the ktor documentation mentioned about that [Here](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#form_parameters).
but i am not clear how to do that. anyone please help me.

FYI, I'm new to kmm and ktor

Comment: Have you tried the example from https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#upload_file?

Comment: yes, but i'm sharing the value as String only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ktor client post multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830965/ktor-client-post-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer after trying several times!

```
            val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.post(endpoint) {
                headers {
                    append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, getAuthToken())
                }
                setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(
                    formData {
                        append("attachment", attachment)}))
            }
```

We can add key and value in body as form-data as string like shown in above!