# Problem translating retrofit multipart call to ktor

Tags: kotlin, http-headers, retrofit, ktor, ktor-client

Really stuck with translating multipart request from retrofit to ktor client.

In retrofit I have following method:

```
 @Multipart
 @POST("rest/sendPhotos")
 suspend fun sendPhotos(@Part files: List<MultipartBody.Part>): Response<ResultDto>
```

in datasource layer it's called as:

```
fun sendFiles(files: List<File>): Response<ResultDto> {
    val parts = mutableListOf<MultipartBody.Part>()
    files.forEachIndexed { index, file ->
        val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("multipart/form-items".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image_$index", file.name, requestFile)
        parts.add(part)
    }
    return mainApiService.sendPhotos(parts)
}
```

In ktor I'm trying to translate it as:

```
    private suspend fun sendFiles(files: List<File>): HttpResponse {
        val parts = mutableListOf<PartData>()
        files.forEachIndexed { index, file ->
            val part = formData {
                append("content", InputProvider(file.length()) { file.inputStream().asInput() }, Headers.build {
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "multipart/form-items")
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=\"${file.name}\"; name=\"image_$index\"")
                })
            }
            parts.addAll(part)
        }
        return httpClient.post("rest/sendPhotos") {
            setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(
                parts = parts,
            ))
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work... Tried zillion variants, but helpless. Trying to fix it several days, unfortunately ktor logging can't help me, since it doesn't show body, printing smth like: `[request body omitted]`

Can anyone please help me? Any ideas or clues?

**Added**
Retrofit logger reads:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=0574af17-6a38-4888-af48-b368c4ce0f79
17:57:03.773  D  Content-Length: 209034
17:57:03.773  D  ticket: 00204e0d1669ccee81e6410390e48e530ba80c0c
17:57:03.788  D  
17:57:03.793  D  --0574af17-6a38-4888-af48-b368c4ce0f79
                 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_0"; filename="2024-01-03-00-56-48-232.jpg"
                 Content-Type: multipart/form-items
                 Content-Length: 208249
```

I can't get similar logs from ktor, it shows nothing except *logs omitted* - it's ugly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Retrofit logs, the equivalent Ktor code should be the following:

```
client.post("rest/sendPhotos") {
    setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
        files.forEachIndexed { index, file ->
            append("image_$index", file.readBytes(), Headers.build {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "multipart/form-items")
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=\"${file.name}\"")
            })
        }
    }))
}
```

Comment: just for future references by someone: key parameter quotes in `append()`, should be escaped, like: `append("\"image_$index\"", ...)`

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of issues in your Ktor code that might be causing the problem, I'm rewriting the code, here it is -

```kotlin
private suspend fun sendFiles(files: List<File>): HttpResponse {
    val parts = mutableListOf<PartData>()
    files.forEachIndexed { index, file ->
        val part = formData {
            appendInput(
                "files",
                file.name,
                InputProvider { file.inputStream().asInput() },
                headersOf(
                    HttpHeaders.ContentType to listOf(ContentType.Application.OctetStream.toString()),
                    HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition to listOf(
                        ContentDisposition.File.withParameter(ContentDisposition.Parameters.Name, "image_$index")
                            .toString()
                    )
                )
            )
        }
        parts.add(part)
    }
    return httpClient.post("rest/sendPhotos") {
        setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(parts))
    }
}
```

I Used `appendInput` instead of append in `formData` to handle file input correctly.
Also, `ContentType.Application.OctetStream` for file content type. Furthermore, `ContentDisposition.File` to handle file disposition correctly.

I assume that the server is expecting the files to be sent as "files". You might need to adjust the `files` part in appendInput based on your server requirements.

And also, make sure to check the server documentation for the correct field names and types. If the issue persists, you might want to inspect the server logs to see if there are any error messages or to verify that the request is being received as expected.

Hope it helps!

Comment: not sure it will work - especially with "files" append, server side is already working with Retrofit calls, I can't change it. Nevertheless I will try

Comment: I tried your variant - useless - it doesn't work. In question I have added retrofit logs - please look at them